# Is the Decoder mask (triangular mask) applied only in the first decoder block, or to all blocks in Decoder?

Tags: transformer, attention

The Decoder mask, also called "look-ahead mask", is applied in the Decoder side to prevent it from attending future tokens. Something like this:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But is this mask applied only in the first Decoder block? Or to all its blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The masking should be applied to all Decoder blocks, otherwise in some blocks, past words can attend to future words, which would be cheating during training.

This is reflected in [The Annotated Transformer](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html) as well. Notice that in the Decoder class, the forward function applies the same mask to each layer of the decoder:

```
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    "Generic N layer decoder with masking."
    def __init__(self, layer, N):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = clones(layer, N)
        self.norm = LayerNorm(layer.size)
        
    def forward(self, x, memory, src_mask, tgt_mask):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, memory, src_mask, tgt_mask)
        return self.norm(x)
```